# Arduino Galileo: compile error when using ros

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed the Arduino IDE 1.5.3 for a Galileo-Board. Following the instructions on the wiki, I installed rosserial from github, and "catkin_make"ed and "catkin_make install"ed my ws. Everything worked fine.

When I came to run "rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .", it stops with an error:

```
*** Warning, failed to generate libraries for the following packages: ***
    map_msgs
```

According to several posts and viewing the source of make_libraries.py, this should not be too bad, because generating the messages is the last thing done (correct?). Still, I'd be glad if someone knows how to fix this.

My actual problem is when I compile any of the ROS examples, I get something like

```
Arduino: 1.5.3 (Linux), Board: "Intel® Galileo"

done
xyz.cpp.o: In function `ArduinoHardware::init()':
/home/moritz/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:96: undefined reference to `HardwareSerial::begin(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To me this looks like a linker error(?), but that does not help me any further. Compiling simple examples and uploading them to the board works fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129961/arduino-galileo:-compile-error-when-using-ros/) by [Moritz Maus](https://answers.ros.org/users/12036/moritz-maus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, I came to the conclusion that the Galileo-System does not operate well with ROS (at least currently), so we will potentially switch to another (Arduino?) platform.

I checked the general (non-Galileo) IDE - it does not seem to have any problem with ROS, that is, I can compile the ROS examples. However it does not support the Galileo-board :(

---

Originally posted by [Moritz Maus](https://answers.ros.org/users/12036/moritz-maus/) with karma: 16 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0